# set onClickListener with LinearLayout, ImageView, TextView

Tags: android, android-layout, onclicklistener

I have a Linear Layout with ImageView (icon) and TextView ("Settings") inside. Like this :

[image]

I would like when the user clicks on the LinearLayout or ImageView or TextView, another Actitivy is started.

So I do this in the code:

```
OnClickListenerLessons mOnClickListener = new mOnClickListenerLessons(){
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), nextActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
            }}

imageView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
linearLayout.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
textView.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);
```

And I found that it is quite bulky and messy, is there anyway to make the code cleaner?

Many thanks!

P.S: here is my xml file

```
 <LinearLayout>
     ...
      <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_wrapper_lessons"
            style="@style/width_height_margin_for_items"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lessons_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/puzzle_piece" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home_lesson_textView"
                style="@style/text_view"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/home_lesson_button" />
        </LinearLayout>
    ...
</LinearLayout>
```

here is the style.xml for text_view

```
<style name="text_view">
    <item name="android:background">@null</item>
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">5dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/home_buttons_select_state_color</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you set an `onClickListener` to `TextView` or `ImageView`, you should also declare those as `android:clickable="true"` or `setClickable(true)`.

Also having a `LinearLayout` with an `ImageView` and a `TextView` might not be necesseary, why don't you just add the image with `android:drawableLeft`? Nesting `LinearLayouts` is a very bad habit.

Comment: using android:drawableLeft is very good advice, thanks! It works for me!

Answer (score 1):

Implement `OnClickListener` in your activity and override the `onClick()` method and write in this manner

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch(v.getId()){
        case R.id.imageView1:
        case R.id.textview1:
        case R.id.linearlayout1:
            Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), nextActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

    }
```

You can have a case of linearlayout only because your controls are within it

Comment: This one seems to be very effective to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Arrange components in layout XML as bellow

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Hello, I am a TextView" />
    <Image android:="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then add click listener for `LinearLayout`

`linearLayout.setOnClickListener(mOnClickListener);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have tried to setOnlickListener only for linearLayout and ignore the textView, when I click on the text, it does not start the new activity. When I tried to click on the space between the imageView and the textView (which is the space belonging to linearLayout) it starts the new activity I want. That's why I am stuck with having to set OnClickListener for them all.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the TextView and ImageView inside the LinearLayout, is useless to set the click listener on them if you don't need to handle different actions of the click listener of the parent.

You just need to do:

```
linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(getActivity(), nextActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }}
});
```

Comment: I have tried to setOnlickListener only for linearLayout and ignore the textView, when I click on the text, it does not start the new activity. When I tried to click on the space between the imageView and the textView (which is the space belonging to linearLayout) it starts the new activity I want. That's why I am stuck with having to set OnClickListener for them all.

Comment: @mochi But in your xml file your LinearLayout is the PARENT of textview and imageview?

Comment: sorry Fondesa, let me upload my xml file.

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use single button with image and text.then set button width and height match_parent.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/ButtonTest"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:paddingTop="32sp"
    android:text="this is text"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the below line to your both child views,

> android:clickable="false"

Like this,

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linear_layout_wrapper_lessons"
            style="@style/width_height_margin_for_items"
            android:layout_weight="25"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/lessons_icon"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/puzzle_piece"
                android:clickable="false" /> 
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/home_lesson_textView"
                style="@style/text_view"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:text="@string/home_lesson_button" 
                android:clickable="false"/>
        </LinearLayout>
```